# Positional Tracking System

Tags: c#, bluetooth, signals, wifi

I am developing a system to track position of a swimmer in a swimming lane. The swimming lane being the standard olympic size of 50 meters in length and 2.5 meters in width.

My idea is to have one transmitter on the swimmer him/herself. And four receivers, one on each corner of the swimming lane. This also being called multilateration.

The problem I'm running into is the question of what signal type to use, as I've read somewhere on the internet that Wi-Fi signals don't pass through water, which would then make it inaccurate if the swimmer would submerge. This leaves me with a hole in the data which I'm trying to avoid.
I have found a possible solution with a transmitter on the body of the swimmer it being: https://glneurotech.com/bioradio/physiological-signal-monitoring/wireless-motion-sensor/ but with that I'm worried that the signal might not be strong enough as it is only 10 meters through bluetooth.

Is anyone experienced with sending signal waves through water, and would it be more accurate to use a single transmitter with four receivers, or four transmitters and one receiver as stated on this wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilateration and could share his/her solution with me?

Comment: Will there be multiple swimmers? What about sonar?

Comment: It would be to track a single swimmers speed. I don't think sonar would be good for that for possible inaccuracy.